# How do you read in a number and a string from a file in C? Keeping in mind that some lines in the file only has a number and not a string

Tags: c

I have a file with multiple lines, and on each line there is a number followed by a space and then a string. But some lines in the file do not have a string following the digit. Here is part of the file:

> 10
>   17
>   38 So You Want to Be a Rock 'N' Roll Star
>   22 Have You Seen Her Face
>   12 C.T.A. - 102
>   16 Renaissance Fair
>   12 Time Between
>   23 Everybody's Been Burned
>   18 Thoughts and Words
>   12 Mind Gardens
>   13 My Back Pages
>   21 The Girl with No Name
>   3 Why
>   19 It Happens Each Day
>   16 Don't Make Waves
>   13 My Back Pages
>   12 Mind Gardens
>   11 Lady Friend
>   18 Old John Robertson
>   19
>   13 Ice Cream Man
>   14 Hang on Sloopy

Here is what i have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct 
  {
    int num_tracks;
    char tracks[];
  }album_store;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  album_store album[10000];
  int numb_tracks;
  char line;
  int i=0;

if (argc <2 )
{
    printf("You need at least one argument\n");
}

else
{
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen(argv[1],"r");

    while(fscanf(file,"%d %[^\n]",&numb_tracks,album[i].tracks) != EOF)
    {
        album[i].num_tracks=numb_tracks;
        printf("%d %s\n",album[i].num_tracks,album[i].tracks);
        i++;
    }
}

}
```

Now my code reads in the lines, but not the spaces. Or rather it does not know how to detect if a line does not have a string after the digit. The output of my code looks like:

> 10 17
>   38 So You Want to Be a Rock 'N' Roll Star
>   22 Have You Seen Her Face
>   12 C.T.A. - 102
>   16 Renaissance Fair
>   12 Time Between
>   23 Everybody's Been Burned
>   18 Thoughts and Words
>   12 Mind Gardens
>   13 My Back Pages
>   21 The Girl with No Name
>   3 Why
>   19 It Happens Each Day
>   16 Don't Make Waves
>   13 My Back Pages
>   12 Mind Gardens
>   11 Lady Friend
>   18 Old John Robertson
>   19 13 Ice Cream Man

My question is how do i get the output of my code to match the input from the file? What would i have to change in my code? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You can't (reasonably) use `fscanf()` unless you know that all your lines are exactly the same correct format. Instead, I would suggest using `fgets()` to get one *line* of text at a time, then parse that line (perhaps using `sscanf()`).

For example,

```
char buf[1000];
while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file) != NULL) {
    sscanf(buf,"%d %[^\n]",&numb_tracks,album[i].tracks);
    // etc
}
```

You'll want to add checking of the return value of `sscanf()` to the above sample.